# Blender object alpha channel question

Tags: transparency

When you are rendering to render layers how do I get blender to keep alpha data from objects in  going into the compositor? It doesn't seem to bring in object alpha data.

Comment: Which object alpha data? How are you rendering the layers? How did you setup the compositing? Could you please provide more information and show screenshots of what your problem is?

Comment: Please set up the simplest example you can think of, to illustrate your particular case, showing us the relevant parts of the pipeline.  You can embed screen-grabs of the UI and results in your post. You can share your stripped down example on https://blend-exchange.com/, too,

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have uploaded the simplest version of this onto blender exchange - link below. a cube and a sphere both in their own collections and both in their own render layers - when I go into composite where i want the renderer to put them together as they appear in layout but there is no alpha channel on each layer (completely white). I'm trying to avoid rendering out each layer hoping to do it all inside the renderer  ([<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=bGbo82SJ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/bGbo82SJ/) - also https://blend-exchange.com/b/bGbo82SJ -

Comment: Layout https://ibb.co/2nFdc8f

Comment: No Alpha in the compositor - https://ibb.co/Rz009pJ

Comment: I guess I'm trying to use Blender like Nuke where you can render 3d elements into the footage without going the intermendiate step of rendering out image sequences,

Comment: enable "Transparent" in "Film" settings: https://i.imgur.com/dJAQStv.png

Comment: Thank you Markus von Broady! That's it!! Much appreciated!!! Woohoo!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the "Transparent" setting in the rendering-film category had to be enabled.

[image]